# Determine circles equation based on two points.

Tags: vectors, circles

I asked this question before which gave me a solution, but the more I thought about it I still have some questions regarding this and am looking to see if my thinking is correct.

You have two points $S=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ on a circle. What is the equation for the family of circles that can share these two points?

My thought process so far:

[image]

$$\vec{u}=\vec{QP}, \vec{v}=\vec{SP}, P=(x,y)$$
Distance "a" is half distance of $\vec{QS}$ and together with $\tan{\theta}$ gives us "b", distance to center. For any $\tan{\theta}=\text{constant}$ we have two possible circles, A and B and which is it depends on the sign of $tan{\theta}$. So, if:$$\tan{\theta}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\Leftrightarrow \cos{\theta}-\lambda \sin{\theta}=0$$
We can represent $\sin{\theta}=\frac{\vec{u}\times\vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|}$
, but $\cos{\theta}=\pm\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|}$ depending on whether P is on the same side of the line as the center or not. On one side the angle  between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $\theta$ and the other side the angle is $180-\theta$ which changes sign of $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$.

The equation I was supposed to get to is:

$$\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|}-\lambda\frac{\vec{u}\times\vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|}=0\Leftrightarrow \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}-\lambda\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=0$$
But it seems to me that the equation only works for P on the same side of the line as the center.

I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of any circle of the family of circles passing through $S$ and $Q$ can be written as

$ C = \dfrac{1}{2} (S + Q) + \lambda U $

were $U$ is perpendicular to $(S - Q)$

Then the equation of that circle is

$(r - C)^T (r -C) = (S - C)^T (S - C)$

where $r = [x, y]^T $

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is certainly a solution. Although I foresee a lot of calculations with that method. That's why I hoped that there were some sleek solution that only involved scalar and cross product of two vectors, since that seems to involve less variables and calculation to get an equation.